# How to customize uitableview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

How do I customize each cell in a `UITableView` (like each cell will have `UITextfield` and `UIButton`)?

Answer (score 3):

`UITableView` cells respond to selections - it get's handled in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, maybe this satisfies your UIButton requirement. In case where you need UIButton it should not be difficult - it is just another UIView component.

[Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) is a detailed article on customizing `UITableView`. It goes beyond what you want but you may find useful details. Have a look at section **Layout within the contentView** for how to add views to cell - the example adds image and text (lots of custom background stuff going on).

Example code discussed [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8024294):

```
UIView* container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:goodRect];
UITableView* tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableRect];
UIButton* btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:btnFrame];

[container addSubview:tv];
[container addSubview:btn];

myController.view = container;
```

Maybe have a look at question [UIButton in a UITableView header ignores most touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297297/uibutton-in-a-uitableview-header-ignores-most-touches).

Answer (score 1):

There  era a few subViews in table cell that you can modify. Good tutorial that I found is here: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: I thought of that one as well - classic tutorial.