# delaysContentTouches = false not Working in UITableView Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have **UIButton** inside cell of **UITableView**, When i touch the button it is actually working but the ***animation*** of highlighted is not being seen, I have tried setting **delaysContentTouches = false** on viewDidLoad and also on **IB**

I even tried to find UIScrollVIew of table view so that i can set that properties to **false**, like...

```
 for cls in cell.subviews
    {
        println("name of class is ::\(NSStringFromClass(cls.classForCoder))")
        if NSStringFromClass(cls.classForCoder) == "UITableViewCellScrollView"
        {
       cls.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
            break
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19299451/3755954

Comment: i already have tried that @cyberlobe

Comment: Any news on this?...I'm in the same boat. None of the proposed solutions I've seen are working (if let scrollview = subview as? UIScrollView is always evaluating to false for me).

Answer (score 1):

UITableView subclass

```
override public var delaysContentTouches: Bool {
    didSet {
      if let subviews = self.subviews as? [UIView] {
        for view in subviews {
          if let scroll = view as? UIScrollView {
            scroll.delaysContentTouches = delaysContentTouches
          }
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: humm thats what i have already tried ! in new layout table view does not have that scroll view properties !

Comment: your code is find cell.subview.scrollView, what is this?