# UITableview does not immediately respond to cell selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView where each cell triggers a modal view (it is a travel planner, the table is used to select origin and destination).

After selecting an address the modal is dismissed and the user is returned to the tableview. However, if I immediately select a cell the event is not recoginized, I need to wait a few seconds.

I've checked that neither shouldHighlightCellAtIndexPath or didSelectCellAtIndexPath is called.

After checking other questions here I also tried to set delaysContentTouches to false (for tableview and the embedded scrollview, see [UIButton not showing highlight on tap in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256996/uibutton-not-showing-highlight-on-tap-in-ios7))

Do anyone know how I can make the tableview respond to selection immediately? The delay is just long enough to annoy the users

Comment: are you dismissing this modal views with animated = true ?

Comment: and next question - is there any complex code in viewWillAppear ? maybe your UI just become unresponsive because it is hands somewhere there on lock or something.

Comment: Your first comment was the key issue here. The table was unreponsive while the modal was being dismissed. I assume this isn't something I can change so I've removed the animation and things work fine again :)

Comment: if it will work for you then great, but if you'll need animation look for UITransitionDelegate and implement custom anmation that will look like standard but increas speed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my client was satisfied with just removing the animation

Answer (score 0):

First of all on tap on `UITableViewCell`, delegate that gets called is `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. This gets triggered instantaneously - always!

My guess is you are doing some networking on your main thread on tap on cell and then presenting new screen with that data. This would make UI look delayed and un-responsive. Please double check and ensure all non-UI stuff that need not require main thread goes in a parallel thread.