# How to disable delaysContentTouches in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have `UITableViewController`, inside it i have custom `UITableViewCell` with `UIButton`. On click at button i have delay before highlighted effect.

This code in `viewDidLoad` don't help me:

```
self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

How to disable this delay effect, and have highlighted after click (not long touch)

Comment: @remus i don't have UITableViewCellScrollView in subviews of my cell with button

Comment: @remus oh god, sorry, ill try

Comment: @remus [in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256996/uibutton-not-showing-highlight-on-tap-in-ios7) guy said subviews of cell, where i should use it? He said "iOS 7 we have one control UITableViewCellScrollView In between UITableViewCell and content View." Should i use it before return cell?

Comment: Oh, my comment was removed. I linked to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24665644/1214800) originally -- I think that's the one that actually works.

Comment: @remus HOLY PONY ITS WORKS, amazing! Thanx very much! I can vote ur help as complete answer